# Trouble using AndroidSlidingPanel

Tags: android, xml, slider, slide

I am trying to use [this android sliding panel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) in my application.

The problem is, it is taking up my whole screen and intercepting all clicks, no matter where I click, it just opens and closes the panel. I'd like it to be at the bottom and I just drag it up to show the content then drag it down to remove the content.

How can I achieve this?

Here is my xml code.

NOTE: I have tried putting the tab below something low in my screen but that makes the content not show much... I cannot find a way around this. Any help is appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/whole_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/behindChessBoard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/chessBoard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:columnCount="8"
            android:rowCount="8" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cell00"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"

            android:background="@color/chessTan"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:contentDescription="00" />

        ... ... .. . .. ...
        </GridLayout>

        <View 
            android:id="@+id/fakeView"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <View 
            android:id="@+id/fakeViewTop"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/checkText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/soundSwitch"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="@color/win8_red" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/undoButton"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fakeView"
            android:layout_above="@+id/fakeView"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/redoButton"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fakeView"
            android:layout_above="@+id/fakeView"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/changeBoardColorsButton"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:clickable="true" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chessBoard"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/loadButton"
            android:clickable="true" />-->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/doneButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="Done"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/blacksTurnIndicator1"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:button="@layout/radio_selector"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/chessBoard"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/blacksTurnIndicator2"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/chessBoard"
            android:button="@layout/radio_selector"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/blacksTurnIndicator1" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/blacksTurnIndicator3"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/chessBoard"
            android:button="@layout/radio_selector"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blacksTurnIndicator1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/whitesTurnIndicator1"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chessBoard"
            android:checked="true"
            android:button="@layout/radio_selector"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/whitesTurnIndicator2"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chessBoard"
            android:checked="true"
            android:button="@layout/radio_selector"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/whitesTurnIndicator1" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/whitesTurnIndicator3"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:button="@layout/radio_selector"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chessBoard"
            android:checked="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/whitesTurnIndicator1" />
        <com.example.chess.SlidingUpPanelLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top">

          <RelativeLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="bottom" >

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:gravity="top|left"
                  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/messageEditText"
                  android:textColor="@color/white"
                  android:textSize="18sp" />

              <EditText
                  android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:hint="Enter message..."
                  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendMessageButton"
                  android:textColor="@color/white"
                  android:textSize="18sp"
                  android:maxLines="2" />
              <ImageButton
                  android:id="@+id/sendMessageButton"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:src="@drawable/send_message_button"
                  android:scaleType="fitXY"
                  android:padding="0dp"
                  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                  android:visibility="invisible"
                  android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

          </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:textColor="@color/DarkGoldenrod"
            android:text="Chat"
            android:textSize="28sp" />
        </com.example.chess.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the link you provided for the library it states

> To use the layout, simply include com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout as the **Root element** in your activity Layout.

Please read the documentation, its clear enough.

Comment: The problem is, the slider can only have two children, one for the slider, and one for the content in the panel. In that case, where is the content that shows when the panel is hidden supposed to go?

Comment: **The first child is your main layout. The second child is your layout for the sliding up panel. Both children should have width and height set to match_parent.**

Just have two frame layouts as children of the sliding panel layout and add fragments to those framelayouts in your code. Fragments can have their own layout hierarchy.